# how to  get the right format for GPS data in android

Tags: android, dictionary, gps

I have an app that does a query to a database.....asking for GPS data (latitude and longitude) which I animate on thr map afterwards.

Everything goes as expeected data like this

48868658

48869320

48869320
 is returned and I display them on the map but when the cursor reaches to numbers like this:

48874808.0

I get the following error:

java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '4.88748e+07' as integer

which I don't understand cause in my code I did this:

longitude = (int)Integer.parseInt(c.getString(1));

latitude = (int)Integer.parseInt(c.getString(2));

p = new GeoPoint(latitude, longitude);

I've casted the whole thing to int....but I still get that error which stops my map.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

48874808.0 is a float or double, on the other hand, 48874808 is an integer.

To get the integral part, you can try something like this:

```
double d = Double.parse("48874808.0");
int integral = (int) d;
```

Comment: Ya but I cast it to integer and after that I should have 48874808 instead of 48874808.0 and everything should go well,isn't it?

Comment: Not really. 48874808.0 can only, as far as I know, be casted to float or double. If you want the integral part, cast 48874808.0 to float, and then, cast that result into integer. I'll  be changing my answer shortly.

Comment: And this should go also with:48869320....If I do (int)Double.parse(48869320) after that I should have 48869320?????

Comment: 48869320 can be directly cast to integer,  but if you want a universal solution, you can cast everything to double and then back to integer. That will work.